# Как различать наречие и существительное с предлогом?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, слитно-раздельно, наречия, существительные

Запутался вконец. Думал, что — по наличию пояснительного слова, но тут прочитал некоторые примеры и увидел, что они пишутся слитно, хотя я бы написал раздельно.

Понятно, когда слово — наречие.

1. Он живёт наверху — здесь.

А что насчёт этого?

2. "Гнездо свили (на)верху ели", "Флаг поставили (на)верху дома".

Примеры под цифрой 2 написал бы раздельно, имея в виду существительное с предлогом. Как же всё-таки их различать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Гнездо свили **наверху ели**. Флаг поставили **наверху дома**.*

**Пояснение**

1. В данной теме следует отличать **наречный предлог НАВЕРХУ** от предлога НА перед существительным при наличии зависимых слов

**2. Из словарей**

Орфографический словарь: **наверху**, нареч. и предлог (сидеть наверху; гнездо наверху ели), но сущ. **на верху** (**на плоской поверхности** подъемного навеса, крыши); быть на верху блаженства

**НАВЕРХУ. II. предлог.** В верхней части чего-л. Флаг наверху мачты. Гнездо наверху сосны.

3. Предлог НА предполагает наличие **плоской поверхности** (верх чего-либо), в противном случае используется наречный предлог НАВЕРХУ (это более частотный вариант).

**Верх ели** – это верхушка дерева или его верхняя часть, но там нет плоской поверхности. **Верх дома** – это нечто неопределенное, поэтому здесь аналогичная ситуация.

**4. Примеры**

(1) Сидя **на верху** **длинной деревянной стремянки**, мягким вороньим крылом сметал пыль с корешков почерневших от времени фолиантов…[Василь Быков. Главный кригсман (2002)]

Назар стоял **на верху крыльца**, напыжившись, расставив свои крепенькие ноги гнома…[Юрий Трифонов. Предварительные итоги (1970)]

(2) Вот и делают круглую деревянную нашлепку **наверху мачты** ― клотик. [Андрей Некрасов. (1937-1939)]

Домик был самый настоящий ― окна со стеклами, двери сами закрываются. **Наверху дома** мезонинчик. [К. С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть. Часть 1. Хлыновск (1930)]

Так прошло более часа, и в полночной тишине слышала она скрип флюгера **наверху дома** … [А. С. Грин. Джесси и Моргиана (1928)]

**Наверху табло** высвечивало номер очереди и стрелкой указывало, в какое именно билетно-кассовое отверстие вы должны обратиться... «Столица», 1997.05.13]

Comment: Почему в словаре Бучкиной примеры с "наверху", которые вы написали слитно, написаны раздельно. Там не написано, что вообще в роли предлога "наверху" употребляется.

Comment: Это написано в орфографическом словаре РАН, вполне серьезный источник, обновляется каждый год. Очень рекомендую.http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=наверху&all=x  А примеры из Нацкорпуса, можете над ними поразмышлять сами, то есть соглашаться с мнением известных писателей или нет. И уточните год издания словаря Букчиной.

Comment: 2011. Кстати, с РАН этот словарь тоже связан, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Связан был 10 лет назад, а сейчас 2022 год. Заходите на Грамоту, чего же проще. Там официальный словарь,  а у вас Букчина.  Словарей много издавалось, да только один контролируется РАН постоянно.

Comment: Букчина — член Орфографической комиссии при Отделении историко-филологических наук РАН. Не хухры-мухры.

Comment: Замечательно! Возможно, она даже принимает участие в обновлении словаря. И что из этого?

Comment: Нет уже её.....

Comment: Речь тут не о том, чтобы свериться со словарем, здесь речь о том, чтобы понять логику правописания без словаря. Я никогда не видел конкретного правила по таким словам, как "вверху", "наверху", их не включают в какие-то исключения из правил. А правило обычно одно видел: есть зависимое слово - значит это существительное с предлогом.

Comment: И ведь должна же быть в правилах какая-то системность, нельзя же обращаться к словарю по поводу каждого примера или слова.

Comment: Чудесно! Я вам объяснила всю логику, а вы не говорите, что вы этой логики не поняли. Вы  начинаете разговоры о СЛОВАРЯХ. Вы недовольны, что не слышали о наречном предлоге НАВЕРХУ, но кто в этом виноват. Если вы видите слитное написание "наверху" перед существительным, какая это часть речи. Посмотрите в Нацкорпусе, там много таких вариантов. Я внимательно готовилась к ответу на вопрос и могу это подтвердить. Но вы мне не доверяете.  Гнездо на верху елки. Должна быть некая плоскость,  НА которую положено гнездо, а ее там нет.  Это особенность предлога НА  – направление на плоскость.

Comment: Хорошо. С елью убедили, но с домом?

Comment: Черным по белому в словаре написано, его не глупый человек писал. Ср. предлог с сущ. на верху: Флаг на верху дома.

Comment: В каком словаре? Букчиной?  Словарь РАН обновляется каждый год. Значит, теперь надо писать слитно, теперь это предлог. Лично мне такое написание ближе, верх дома – это необязательно плоскость, там башенки есть. Может, флаг к башенке прикрутили.

Comment: Да и вообще, верх любого предмета – это нечто неопределенное, поэтому эта форма устаревает, наречный предлог встречается чаще. Будьте наблюдательны, читая литературу.

Answer (score 1):

Разница такова:
*наверху* — вверху (заменяем другим обстоятельством);
*на верху* — на верхней части (заменяем предложным сочетанием). || Поэтому в орфографическом словаре говорится о плоской поверхности.

Стилистику после таких замен учитывать не нужно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138692/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-------).